# SQLite how to merge different tables

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlite

Here are the codes for the tables

```
CREATE TABLE oneusd ( NAME TEXT,PRICEDATE TEXT,
PRICE INTEGER );

CREATE TABLE twoeur ( NAME TEXT,PRICEDATE TEXT,
PRICE INTEGER );

CREATE TABLE euravg ( PRICEDATE TEXT,
PRICE INTEGER );

CREATE TABLE holiday ( HOLIDAY TEXT);

CREATE TABLE eurusd (PRICEDATE TEXT,
PRICE INTEGER );

INSERT INTO oneusd VALUES
("PriceUSD","2018-04-27",402.75),("PriceUSD","2018-04-30", 438.75),
("PriceUSD","2018-05-01",428.75),("PriceUSD","2018-05-02", 437.00);


INSERT INTO twoeur VALUES
("PriceUSD","2018-04-27",45.11792),("PriceUSD","2018-04-28", 38.63375),
("PriceUSD","2018-04-29",35.03250),("PriceUSD","2018-04-30", 32.26875),
("PriceUSD","2018-05-02", 35.76292);


INSERT INTO euravg VALUES
("2018-04-27",45.11792),("2018-04-28", 38.63375),
("2018-04-29",35.03250),("2018-04-30", 32.26875),
("2018-05-01", 21.48625),("2018-05-02", 35.76292);


INSERT INTO eurusd VALUES
("2018-04-27",1.2070),("2018-04-30", 1.2079),
("2018-05-02", 1.2007);


INSERT INTO holiday VALUES
("2018-05-01");
```

In the final table should be all dates from tables oneusd, twoeur, eurusd. However, the row with date "2018-05-01" should have all NULLs. In the final table I wanted to have only one PRICEDATE and PRICE (per Table) columns, however when I was using different kind of JOINs and UNIONs (FULL OUTER JOIN does not work in SQLite) I have correct information, but in many columns (column PRICEDATE always repeated). Could you hel how to figure it out.

Expected output is following:
[image]

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: I ADDED A SCREEN SHOT. Conditions: 1) all dates (PRICEDATE) from oneusd and twoeur should be included, but the date from holiday should be NULL. Then I need to union/group by PRICEDATE columns PRICE from oneusd euravg and eurusd.

Answer (score 0):

Use `union all` and `group by`:

```
select pricedate, max(oneusd) as oneused, max(euravg) as euravg, max(eurusd) as eurusd
from ((select pricedate, price as oneusd, null as euravg, null as eurusd
       from oneusd
      ) union all
      (select pricedate, null as oneusd, price as euravg, null as eurusd
       from euravg
      ) union all
      (select pricedate, null as oneusd, null as euravg, price as eurusd
       from eurusd
      ) union all
      (select pricedate, null as oneusd, null as euravg, null as eurusd
       from holiday
      )
     ) p
group by pricedate;
```

Obviously, you should include the tables and columns that you want.  The question seems a little unclear on what tables you really need for the query.

Comment: Thank you. I will try to elaborate more. Conditions: 1) all dates (PRICEDATE) from oneusd and twoeur should be included, but the date from holiday should be NULL. Then I need to union/group by PRICEDATE  columns PRICE from  oneusd euravg and eurusd.